# Making a group by with count(*) but return 0 if no joins are made

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following SQL:

```
    select  
    s.Id,
    s.SPOSiteId,
    s.Url,  
    COUNT(*) as ItemCountScan,
    s.ItemCount as ItemCountList,    
    SUM(f.CountUniqueRoleAssignments) as SharedWithCount,
    SUM(s.MemberCount) as MembersCount,
    SUM(s.OwnerCount) as OwnersCount,       
    s.Created,
    s.LastItemUserModifiedDate,
    s.Template,
    s.TimeZoneId,
    s.Language    
    
from sites s
LEFT JOIN Files f ON f.SiteId = s.Id
GROUP BY 
    s.Id,
    s.SPOSiteId,
    s.Url,
    s.ItemCount,
    s.Forvaltning,
    s.KoncernEnhed,
    s.Enhed,
    s.KKOrg,
    s.BestiltAf,
    s.DataAnsvarlig,
    s.DirekteChef,
    s.Created,
    s.LastItemUserModifiedDate,
    s.Template,
    s.TimeZoneId,
    s.Language,
    s.GroupSettings,
    s.ExternalAccess,
    s.Inserted
```

As you can see it joins two tables - files and sites. Everything works as expected unless this in the select:

```
COUNT(*) as ItemCountScan
```

The column should tell how many files are there on the given site. If the site has files it works as expected. However if the site does not have any files then it returns 1 (because the site count it self in the group by). Is there any way to make this work both for sites with no files and sites with files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count something from the second table, such as:

```
COUNT(f.SiteId) as ItemCountScan
```

Comment: Worked! Appreciated. I will answer in 12 mins when possible.

Comment: @ThomasSegato Make sure it's a non-nullable column, common practice is to use the PK

Comment: @Charlieface . . . Actually, I recommend using the column in the `JOIN` expression, because `JOIN` fails if the column is `NULL`.  A primary key or known non-NULL value is also equally valid.

Comment: I used the primary key id. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put the count inside the join.

```sql
    select  
    s.Id,
    s.SPOSiteId,
    s.Url,  
    f.ItemCountScan,
    s.ItemCount as ItemCountList,    
    f.SharedWithCount,
    SUM(s.MemberCount) as MembersCount,
    SUM(s.OwnerCount) as OwnersCount,       
    s.Created,
    s.LastItemUserModifiedDate,
    s.Template,
    s.TimeZoneId,
    s.Language    
    
from sites s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SiteId,
        COUNT(*) as ItemCountScan,
        SUM(f.CountUniqueRoleAssignments) as SharedWithCount
    FROM Files
    GROUP BY SiteId
) f ON f.SiteId = s.Id
GROUP BY 
    s.Id,
    s.SPOSiteId,
    s.Url,
    s.ItemCount,
    s.Forvaltning,
    s.KoncernEnhed,
    s.Enhed,
    s.KKOrg,
    s.BestiltAf,
    s.DataAnsvarlig,
    s.DirekteChef,
    s.Created,
    s.LastItemUserModifiedDate,
    s.Template,
    s.TimeZoneId,
    s.Language,
    s.GroupSettings,
    s.ExternalAccess,
    s.Inserted,
    f.ItemCountScan,
    f.SharedWithCount;
```

This can also be done as a correlated `APPLY`, note that the optimizer is usually able to transform between these two syntaxes and choose the most efficient.

```sql
    select  
    s.Id,
    s.SPOSiteId,
    s.Url,  
    f.ItemCountScan,
    s.ItemCount as ItemCountList,    
    f.SharedWithCount,
    SUM(s.MemberCount) as MembersCount,
    SUM(s.OwnerCount) as OwnersCount,       
    s.Created,
    s.LastItemUserModifiedDate,
    s.Template,
    s.TimeZoneId,
    s.Language    
    
from sites s
CROSS APPLY (     -- or OUTER if you want nulls
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) as ItemCountScan,
        SUM(f.CountUniqueRoleAssignments) as SharedWithCount
    FROM Files
    WHERE f.SiteId = s.Id
    -- GROUP BY ()    -- if you want nulls
) f
GROUP BY 
    s.Id,
    s.SPOSiteId,
    s.Url,
    s.ItemCount,
    s.Forvaltning,
    s.KoncernEnhed,
    s.Enhed,
    s.KKOrg,
    s.BestiltAf,
    s.DataAnsvarlig,
    s.DirekteChef,
    s.Created,
    s.LastItemUserModifiedDate,
    s.Template,
    s.TimeZoneId,
    s.Language,
    s.GroupSettings,
    s.ExternalAccess,
    s.Inserted,
    f.ItemCountScan,
    f.SharedWithCount;
```

This returns `0` as it is a scalar aggregate (no `GROUP BY`). If you want `NULL` instead of `0`, you can switch to `OUTER APPLY` and place `GROUP BY ()` inside the apply.